# Are $\exp^{-a\|x\|^{2}}$ and $f(x) = \exp^{-a|x|^{2}}$ the same? What is $\|x\|$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I want to compute the integral of $f(x)$ using the Monte Carlo integration method.

$f(x) = \exp^{-a\|x\|^{2}}$ over the cube $[-1,1]^n$, where $a$ is any constant and $n$ dimension of space.

$[-1,1]^n$ means $(r_1,r_2,r_3,\dotsc, r_n)$ where   $-1 < r_i < 1$.

I want to know does

$$f(x) = \exp^{-a\|x\|^2}$$
and
$$f(x) = \exp^{-a|x|^{2}}$$
are same?

Here $x$ is a vector of $n$-dimensions (or point in $n$-dimensional space).
So what is $|x|$ and $\|x\|$? Is it a determinant or matrix or vector or something else?
I welcome your hint or pointer to hint. Thank you.

Comment: Without any other symbols or other context, both are used to mean Euclidean norm. But the double bar notation can be used to denote any other norm, usually with subscripts or a note attached somewhere though.

Comment: Normally, |x| is the absolute value function with x a real number while ||x|| is the "norm" on R^n.  If n= 1 they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, without any other context, I would assume that $$|x| = \|x\| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \dotsb + x_n^2}.$$

Comment: thank you @DMcMor